# Always show dojo tooltip

Tags: dojo

I have the following code for adding tooltip for onclick of a span id as shown below:

```
new dijit.Tooltip({
            connectId: ['gridEditHelp'],
            label: 'Double click on an item in the below table to perform inline editing of attributes',
            position: ['above']
});
```

The problem is that I want the tooltip to be visible always on the web page.

Any ideas or existing API available for the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TooltipDialog` instead - or else you will have to mess with the `_MasterTooltip` manager (there's more or less only one global, reusable tooltip). Then call `dijit.popup.open` - and never call `.close`

```
dijit.popup.open({
     popup: new TooltipDialog({
            id: 'myTooltipDialog',
            style: "width: 300px;",
            content: "<p>I have a mouse leave event handler that will close the dialog."
        });,
     around: dojo.byId('thenode')
});
```

Comment: hey mschr, do you have a working sample for that or could you please create a jsfiddle for this.

Comment: im fairly sure this *is* a working sample.. all you need is to load the modules and create 'thenode'

Comment: The problem I am facing is that nothing shows up. If possible, could you please fix this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PVARq/1/